# Spring boot - Multiple Database connections generated by entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have a simple situation and don't know what method/solution is better in performance.

**In the following current method:**

1. I am persisting the entity in order to receive the entity id in order to upload it to s3. I am getting the id with help of Lifecycle.
2. If I generate entity id using UUID.randomUUID().toString() -> spring boot will generate an additional MySQL 'select statement' before insertion which would affect the application performance.
3. When I use emf.createEntityManager(), a new Database connection is created. And the hikari pool size freeze after a while, due to active not closed connections.

**Questions:**
How is it possible to configure EntityManagerFactory, so it uses the current database connection, instead of opening a new one ?

```
    private ProductImage addProductImage(Product product, String url, Boolean uploadImageToS3) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    String productImageUrl = null;
    String productImageId = null;
    try {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        ProductImage productImage = new ProductImage();
        productImage.setOriginalUrl(url);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if(uploadImageToS3) {
            inputStream = getInputStreamFromUrl(url);
            productImage.setSize(getInputStreamSizeOrZero(inputStream));
            productImage.setS3BucketAndEndpoint(storageProperties.getStorageS3ImagesBucketName() + "." + storageProperties.getStorageS3EndPoint());
            productImage.setS3FolderName(S3FolderName.PRODUCTS);
            productImage.setS3Size(S3Size.FULL);
            productImage.setS3Production(storageProperties.getStorageS3Production());
            productImage.setS3CloudFrontDomain(storageProperties.getStorageS3CloudFrontDomain());
        } else {
            productImage.setUri(url);
        }

        em.persist(productImage);
        productImageId = productImage.getId();

        if(uploadImageToS3) {
            productImageUrl = s3StorageService.uploadImage(inputStream, S3FolderName.PRODUCTS, productImageId, S3Size.FULL, allowedImageFormat);
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new CustomGraphQLException("Input stream of the product image could not be closed.");
            } finally {
                em.close();
            }
        } else {
            em.close();
        }
        return productImage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        em.close();
        if(productImageUrl!=null && uploadImageToS3) {
            s3StorageService.deleteImage(S3FolderName.PRODUCTS, productImageId , S3Size.FULL, allowedImageFormat);
        }
        throw new CustomGraphQLException("Product image could not be inserted. " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Why do you manually create the entitymanager and control transactions in the first place?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @JensSchauder, because I want to receive the new Entity id, but to not commit it yet. If I use Transactional annotation, the new created entity will automatically be saved. But I want first to build the entity, upload it's image to s3, and then after doing some additional processes, to save the entity.